# Does an indexed column need crawling?

Tags: 2007, search, caml-query

I am new to SharePoint and was struggling to get this particular information. Please could anyone explain:

1. Will configuring the shared service provider to crawl the content make CAML queries faster?
2. When we index one column in document library, do we need to run the indexing service to keep this index up to date?
3. Will normal search (using CAML query or some Data web part) benefit from having the indexing service configured and crawled, or we need Search web parts?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between the search index and an "Indexed Column."

1. You can [create an Indexed Column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us?correlationid=6c5b7de7-45b1-4f51-8983-56e810a6c556&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#BM2) to increase the speed of a list's views (as well as web parts and CAML queries against that list). This is stored in the database ([more details here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121026150134/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/28/sharepoint-list-performance-how-list-column-indices-really-work-under-the-hood/)). There isn't an indexing service for this.
2. Your content is crawled and stored in the search index. This is managed in your Shared Service Provider (setting up incremental/full crawls for example). You can only query the index using [Enterprise Search SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2007/ms493660%28v=office.12%29). This will NOT improve the performance of your list views / CAML queries.